# How to implement squer brackets parameter with Jax-RS client?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, microprofile

External API is exposing resources with the search parameter.

This is the targeted endpoint:
`https://example.com/api/categories/?filter[name]=[somename]&display=full`

I'm using quarkus with `org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient`. I'm trying to somehow map `filter` parameter with available parameters from `javax.ws.rs` without luck.

The implementation is done for **client**, i don't want to get parameter i want to put them into the request.

```
 @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  CategoriesResponse searchCategoryByName(@DefaultValue("full") @QueryParam("display") String display, <How to implement this param> Filter f
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Get all query parameters, iterate them, and use the ones starting with `filter`.

Comment: This implementation is for client implementation with `org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient` not a server site, this is not relevant

Comment: I've work it around with `@GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  CategoriesResponse searchCategoryByName(@DefaultValue("full") @QueryParam("display") String display, @QueryParam("filter[name]") String string);` but i don't think this is best solution.